# Javascript 'undefined' when using a function variable on an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, undefined

I have the following (example) array of objects:

```
var theArray = [
    {theId:'1', num: 34},
    {theId:'2', num: 23},
    {theId:'5', num: 26}
];
```

and this function, which works fine to loop through them:

```
function printValues() {
    var i = 0;
    for(i; i<theArray.length; i++) {
        var obj = theArray[i];
        document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML += obj.theId + ' = ' + obj.num + '<br>';
    }
}
```

However, if I want to abstract this function for use on similar arrays by using function variables to access objects within them, like this:

```
function printValuesVar(arr,elemId,arrId,arrNum) {
    var i = 0;
    for(i; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var obj = arr[i];
        document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML += obj.arrId + ' = ' + obj.arrNum + '<br>';
    }
}
```

'undefined' is the result when called as below (as I'd kind of expect since 'arrId' is not an object name):

```
printValuesVar(theArray,'result2','theId','num');
```

How can I use the values passed to the function's variables to access values of objects within the array by name?

---

rewritten following advice against antipatterns:

```
function printValuesVar(arr,elemId,arrId,arrNum) {
    var i = 0;
    var content = '';
    for(i; i<arr.length; i+=1) {
        var obj = arr[i];
        content += obj[arrId] + ' = ' + obj[arrNum] + '<br>';
    }
    document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML = content;
}
```

Comment: Your code contains several anti-patterns: (1) You query via `getElementById` inside a loop - there is no need for that. Just get the reference beforehand; (2) you assign to `innerHTML` inside a loop - again no need for that. You want to keep DOM manipulation at a minimum. Construct the HTML string with the loop, and then assign to `innerHTML` *after* the loop.

Comment: +1 for the guidance - since this was a learning process, I rewrote the function (added, above) to incorporate your suggestions, *before* looking at your examples below. Now I'll try the advice from PointedEars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are loking for key "arrId", not the key stored in variable arrId

```
document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML += obj[arrId] + ' = ' + obj[arrNum] + '<br>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function printValuesVar( arr, elemId, arrId, arrNum ) {
    var content = '';

    arr.forEach( function ( arrElem ) {
        content += arrElem[ arrId ] + ' = ' + arrElem[ arrNum ] + '<br>';
    });

    document.getElementById( elemId ).innerHTML = content;
}
```

Or a bit more advanced:

```
function printValuesVar( arr, elemId, arrId, arrNum ) {
    document.getElementById( elemId ).innerHTML = arr.map( function ( arrElem ) {
        return arrElem[ arrId ] + ' = ' + arrElem[ arrNum ];
    }).join( '<br>' );
}
```

*[ES5-shim for shitty browsers](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)*

Comment: Instead of consecutive string concatenation (`+=`) in the loop, consider `push`ing to an `Array` that you `join` later.  A simple `for` loop is likely more efficient and obviously more compatible than either of `forEach` or `map`.

Comment: @PointedEars My second example uses `join()` instead of `+=` string concatenation. The array iteration methods are not implemented in IE8, but you can easily shim that browser. As for efficiency, it's true that `for` is slightly faster than the array methods, but [that doesn't mean it's preferred](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTEqr0IlFKY#t=19m46s).

Comment: `var content = []; for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) { var arrElem = arr[i]; content.push(arrElem[arrId] + ' = ' + arrElem[arrNum]); } ….innerHTML = content.join("<br>");` is likely *a lot* faster and obviously more compatible than consecutive function calls from `forEach` with concatenation. As for the Crockford reference, that fallacy is called "argument from authority", or [ipse dixit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipse_dixit).

Comment: I watched Crockford's lecture too, but am confused about the distinction between `arr.forEach` and `arr.prototype.forEach`... and thanks, Šime, for the shim link.

Comment: @PointedEars No, it's not an argument from authority. An argument from authority would be if I said: "This is better because Crockford says so.". I'm not doing that. My link points to the part of the video where Crockford *explains* why array iteration methods are preferred over `for` loops. Quote: "*The speed difference is not significant and the benefit in the way you can express things in code is really profound.*". This is the argument I'm making.

Comment: @DaveEveritt There is no `arr.prototype.forEach`. Crockford (et al.) are defining `Array.prototype.forEach` when it is not defined, so that the `Array` instance referred to by `arr` can inherit that method through the prototype chain. You can do that, but then you need to take precautions if you want to use `for..in` iteration with `Array` instances (which is handy with sparse arrays), because the new user-defined property is enumerable as well. (The alternative was `Object.defineProperty()`, but if you had that you already had `Array.prototype.forEach` etc.)

Comment: @PointedEars As for your compatibility argument, I've already addressed it above. Iteration methods are not implemented in IE8, but we can shim that browser (ES5-shim). Are you making the argument that iteration methods should be avoided because they're not implemented in IE8?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Crockford's subjective statement is lacking proof, as well as yours, so this *is* only *ipse dixit*.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Where is the logic in writing and using an inefficient shim to achieve greater compatibility when a more efficient, more compatible alternative exists already?

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect this much discussion. FYI I just timed `forEach` and `for` several times with 3 elements: in Safari they take respectively between 2-5 and 0-1 milliseconds. With 100 elements there's no significant change (2-6 and 1-2 ms, although `forEach` took 11 ms on its first run on returning after a few minutes), so unless it's a huge data set I guess it's a case of personal preference... I mean although `forEach` is _technically_ slower, that's not necessarily _the_ reason not to use it?

Comment: @PointedEars Could you please confirm your statement? Are you saying that the ES5 array iteration statements should be **avoided** in favor of `for` statements, because (1) they lack support in IE8, and (2) they perform worse?

Comment: Revised results (removed writing results to `console.log()` and appended to element ID instead): no perceptible speed difference with over 100 elements, both between 0 - 1 ms. Does that help settle the debate? See: http://pastebin.com/FJzyVmhf

Comment: @DaveEveritt Of course it does *not* settle the debate, because the comparison must be made between the *shim* of `Array.prototype.forEach` and the `for` loop in an implementation that does not have built-in `Array.prototype.forEach`. Only then can you make a proper assessment whether the syntactic sugar is worth it.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I am saying that you should very carefully consider whether the syntactic sugar beats the inefficiency inevitably caused by a user-defined emulation of the method. The compatibility issue (and the emulation, which you call "shim", that is required if the method is not built-in) does not only concern IE 8; it concerns *all* ECMAScript implementations that do not have it and the respective runtime environments. For example, there are still companies using Web apps with IE6. Incidentally, such considerations are at the core of [my current research](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix/).

Comment: @PointedEars okay, point taken and thanks for the info; although in some projects I'm not aiming at IE at all, so for an _everyone else_ like me there's not much difference (although I tend to default to `for` and avoid emulation scripts anyway). BTW interesting research. But it's been an informative discussion, so @ŠimeVidas thanks again for the contributions. I've learned all I need to know about this, for now...

Comment: @PointedEars I have taken some time to consider (as you noted), and my conclusion is that the sugar *does* beat the inefficiency in IE8, IE7 and IE6. But this should not surprise you. Now that I've confirmed my position, I would like to hear yours: When proposing solutions to questions concerning arrays on Stack Overflow, which method should be used to iterate them: `for` loops or `forEach` calls? The thing is that you *do* have to choose one - you are not able to submit your solution without making that choice. So what is it?

Comment: False dilemma. You *can* submit your answer without making that choice. Submit one that presents both approaches, pointing out the advantages and disadvantages of each. After all, it is the use-case that defines which approach you should pick (e. g., how many array elements are there; are there target runtime environments, and if yes, which?), and we do not know the use-case.

Comment: @PointedEars Yes, that would be a possibility.